# Open a .pages file on Mac with Python

Tags: python, macos

I want to open a pages doc like this:

```
directory = "/Path/to/file/"
with open(directory+"test.pages") as file:
    data = f.readlines()
    for line in data:
        words = line.split()
        print words
```

Then I got this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/path/to/file/test.pages'
```

Why is this a directory?
And how do I open it then?

Comment: It is a directory- OSX uses bundles which are directories holding several files and treats them as a container. Even so the individual files which you find by using the terminal or python commands will not hold plain text so your code would not work

Comment: I see others have voted to close this one, but I don't think this is too broad. Others might have a similar problem, and while there is no easy answer, there are simple ones, such as I've provided.

Comment: You will probably need to export the file as plain text if you want to manipulate it with python.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, if you accept an answer, you'll get +2 to your rep. Accept the answer you feel helps you the most by clicking checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'/path/to/file/test.pages'` is a directory on your file system, therefore it cannot be opened in Python. Your OS is bundling several files in that directory, and perhaps presenting it as a single package. You could conceivably walk the directory and get the contents:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/path/to/file/test.pages'):
    for file in files:
        print os.path.join(root, file)
```

But opening the files and trying to read in their contents it likely to be fruitless.

I'll show you how to attempt to find any plain-text:

```
import re
# use a pattern that matches for any letter A-Z, upper and lower, 0-9, and _
pattern = re.compile(r'.*\w+.*')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/path/to/file/test.pages'):
    for file in files:
        # open each file with the context manager so it's automatically closed
        # regardless if there's an error. Use the Universal Newlines (U) flag too
        # as a best practice (Unix, Linux, and MS have different newlines).
        with open(os.path.join(root, file), 'rU') as f:
            for line in f:
                if re.match(pattern, line):
                    print line
```

Comment: Thanks. Got an insight into how this works now. The bundle contains a zip-file, some images and plist-files. The plain-text attempt returned a whole bunch of question marks and somewhere in between the text I wrote. Isn't there a way to decrypt this?

Answer (score 0):

I have a Macbook Pro with OSX 10.9.3.

I used your code, and I do not have the issue that you cite.  Since you will be opening a `.pages` file, you will need to decode the file:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Some versions of pages uses bundles, some use a single compressed file. The most recent version of pages (5.2) uses bundles.