# How to use Python to scrape a Pages document and load into a Numbers file

Tags: python, pandas, task

I have a Pages document that has a bunch of quotes written on it. I was to move each quote to its own cell in a Numbers that I would then ready into a Pandas dataframe.

My question is can I automate the transferring for the quotes from Pages to Numbers with Python? Is there another option I am missing? (I assume that I can't convert the Pages document to a PDF since PDF only reads tables is my understanding?)

I haven't tried a solution yet. Just have been doing research and I cannot find anything that I thought could help yet.

Comment: Why don't you export your Pages document as a plain text file (one quote per row). Load this file in python then create an excel or csv document? You can check https://stackoverflow.com/q/24234823/15239951 to read your Pages document directly.